# How can I align a xAxis label to a column highchart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, vuejs3

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
chart: {
    spacing: [0, 0, 0, 0],
    type: 'column',
    inverted: true,
    height: 160,
    marginBottom: 70
},
xAxis: {
    tickWidth: 0,
    type: 'category',
    lineWidth: 0,
    labels: {
        formatter() {
            if (this.value !== 0) {
                return this.value
            }
        },
        style: {
            fontSize: 11,
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            color: '#000'
        }
    }
}
```

**What should I do so that I can align by column?**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERFEr.png

Comment: Hi It would be helpful if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Ilyas Hi, It might be several solution, so could you please provide the sample data that you use or just provide the full config as in the image?